# Shuffle questions in eqexam

Tags: exercises, random

Is there a way of shuffling the questions (not only the answers) using `eqexam`?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: It's not really a problem. I just want to know whether `eqexam` can also shuffle questions. I know that it does shuffle options (in multiple choice problems). I think a MWE won't help much here.

Comment: @NVaughan An MWE isn't just to help us solve a problem – it also saves us time in creating the bare-bones document to play around with.  It's either five minutes for you or five minutes for each and every one of us (potentially summing to hours).

Comment: This has multiple answers here. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17979/exam-class-permute-mc-answer-choices-generate-answer-key